# Summation of the Grand total

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below requirement

[image]

As can be figure out that for every Collector whenever the SubProduct is changing, we are performing it's "SubTotal".

Once the "SubTotal" is over, then we are performing the "Product Total" which is the summation of the "SubProducts" for that collector at the Product level (means until the Product is changed).

and finally, "Grand Total" of that Collector's Product

e.g.
Collector Amreet has 2 Products (NCB and NCT). For NCB he has 2 subProducts viz. Credit Card and Loan. His Product Total is computed at both NCB and NCT level and Grand Total for all the products.

Same is the case for the collector "Vijay"

I have written the below code which is very close to the requirement only thing is that, I'm not able to Add/append Collector Name at the Grand Total Level.

My attempt so far

```
declare @t table(Collector varchar(50),Product varchar(50),SubProduct varchar(50),Amount int)

Insert into @t 
select 'Vijay','NCB','Credit Card',8000 union all
select 'Vijay','NCB','Credit Card',2000 union all
select 'Vijay','NCB','Credit Card',17000 union all
select 'Vijay','NCB','Credit Card',5000 union all
select 'Vijay','NCB','Loan',15000 union all
select 'Vijay','NCB','Loan',5000 union all
select 'Amreet','NCB','Credit Card',3000 union all
select 'Amreet','NCB','Credit Card',1000 union all
select 'Amreet','NCB','Loan',45000 union all
select 'Amreet','NCB','Loan',9000  union all 
select 'Amreet','NCT','Loan',1000 union all
select 'Amreet','NCT','Loan',2000 

Select 
*
from 

(select 
    
  case when grouping(Rn) = 1 then '' else Collector end as Collector,

  case when grouping(Rn) = 1 then '' else Product end as Product,
  
  case 
    when grouping(Collector) = 0 and grouping(Product) = 1 and grouping(SubProduct) = 1 and grouping(Rn) = 1 then 'Grand Total' 
    when grouping(Collector) = 0 and grouping(Product) = 0 and grouping(SubProduct) = 1 and grouping(Rn) = 1 then 'Total(Product Total)' 
    when grouping(Collector) = 0 and grouping(Product) = 0 and grouping(SubProduct) = 0 and grouping(Rn) = 1 then 'SubTotal(Sub Product Total)' 
    else SubProduct end as SubProduct,

  sum(Amount) as Amount

from

(select 
    *, 
    Rn = row_number() over(partition by Collector,Product,SubProduct order by 1/0)  
 from @t) tData 
group by
  rollup(Collector,Product,SubProduct, Rn))x
 
 where x.SubProduct is not null
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just use the same condition you use to decide it's the grand total to also print the collector column? i.e. `case when grouping(Collector) = 0 and grouping(Product) = 1 and grouping(SubProduct) = 1 and grouping(Rn) = 1 then Collector when grouping(Rn) = 1 then '' else Collector end as Collector`. That should look like your requirement, I think.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this one. Here I've added in one things.

```
declare @t table(Collector varchar(50),Product varchar(50),SubProduct varchar(50),Amount int)

Insert into @t 
select 'Vijay','NCB','Credit Card',8000 union all
select 'Vijay','NCB','Credit Card',2000 union all
select 'Vijay','NCB','Credit Card',17000 union all
select 'Vijay','NCB','Credit Card',5000 union all
select 'Vijay','NCB','Loan',15000 union all
select 'Vijay','NCB','Loan',5000 union all
select 'Amreet','NCB','Credit Card',3000 union all
select 'Amreet','NCB','Credit Card',1000 union all
select 'Amreet','NCB','Loan',45000 union all
select 'Amreet','NCB','Loan',9000  union all 
select 'Amreet','NCT','Loan',1000 union all
select 'Amreet','NCT','Loan',2000 

Select 
*
from 

(select 
    
  case when grouping(Rn) = 1 then '' else Collector end as Collector,

  case when grouping(Rn) = 1 then '' else Product end as Product,
  
  case 
    when grouping(Collector) = 0 and grouping(Product) = 1 and grouping(SubProduct) = 1 and grouping(Rn) = 1 then 'Grand Total (' + Collector + ')'
    when grouping(Collector) = 0 and grouping(Product) = 0 and grouping(SubProduct) = 1 and grouping(Rn) = 1 then 'Total(Product Total)' 
    when grouping(Collector) = 0 and grouping(Product) = 0 and grouping(SubProduct) = 0 and grouping(Rn) = 1 then 'SubTotal(Sub Product Total)' 
    else SubProduct end as SubProduct,

  sum(Amount) as Amount

from

(select 
    *, 
    Rn = row_number() over(partition by Collector,Product,SubProduct order by 1/0)  
 from @t) tData 
group by
  ROLLUP(Collector,Product,SubProduct, Rn))x
 
 where x.SubProduct is not null;
```

Comment: Don't put a comment under every answer asking to OP to read your answer. They'll get a notification when you post it; that's all that's needed.  The @ in the comment won't even notify them.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu for informing such a great things.